# Make my github master branch match another branch

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-branch

I've been working on a forked branch "`forkedBranch`" and made many updates to my app. When I was happy with the updates, I went back to my `master` branch (`git checkout master`) and merged my `forkedBranch` (`git merge forkedBranch`). Unfortunately, the `master` branch has lots of problems with it that weren't present in `forkedBranch`.

The app is too complicated for me to want to go through and find all the bugs. Is there a way to make my `master` branch identical to `forkedBranch` to save me the hassle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're absolutely certain you don't need the `master` branch or any of its old commits:

1. `git branch --delete master && git push origin -delete master` - delete the `master` branch locally and on `origin`
2. `git checkout forkedBranch && git pull origin forkedBranch` - pull down the latest `forkedBranch` from `origin`
3. `git checkout -b master && git push origin master` - recreate the `master` branch locally from the latest commit of `forkedBranch`, and push it up to `origin`

Comment: Thanks! What if I want to keep the master branch history? would there be an alternative?

Comment: If you need the `master` branch's history, run these commands first to create and push a backup branch to `origin`: `git checkout master && git pull origin master` then `git checkout -b backup/master && git push origin backup/master`. This will create a branch named `backup/master` that contains all of the commit history of `master`.